# using xubuntu linux, I created a udev rule to capture adding sdc-z* and mount in a directory, but gets mounted again in /media/user as well

Tags: mount, automount, udev, mountpoint

I have written a shell script that is called by a udev rule when a new usb device is added and the partition matches /dev/sd[c-z]* . The shell script does get called, and my shell script mounts it in a specific directory as specified. However the partition also gets mounted in /media/user.

Any ideas why the 'double' mount is happening when running under xubuntu 22.04(latest) ? This doesnt occur when using the same shell script on raspberry pi os.

as indicated above. I thought it might be due to snapd, but snapd did the same in addition to adding a /dev/loop* device to the mounts.

Not sure why automount is still involved since I thought 'stole' the add function using the udev shell script.

Comment: AFAIK automounting of removable media is usually done via udisks, using a distro-specific helper - in Xubuntu, that's thunar-volman I think. See for example [Managing Removable Drives and Media](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/using-removable-media#managing_removable_drives_and_media)